# addsubview from nib file in completionHandler block after checking push notification permissions

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification

I want to check if a device has PushNotification permissions for my app and than to display a dialog.

Therefore I wrote this function:

```
func initPushNotificationDialog() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined) {

            let myView = Bundle.loadView(fromNib: "PushNotificationPermissionView", withType: PushNotificationPermissionView.self)
            myView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
            myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            myView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            myView.center = self.view.center

            myView.layoutIfNeeded()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.addSubview(myView)
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The function is called in viewDidLoad() of the view controller.

This is how the nib file looks like:
[image]

But the problem is, that if I run the app and there are not permissions defined, I get the PushNotificationPermissionView empty with no text inside. After a few seconds displaying empty content suddenly the view gets filled with content.

I didn't understand why and how this behavior is happening. I tried a few things like running it in the main queue and stuff like that but nothing worked. I want that the content is getting filled directly.

If I create the Dialog view not in completionHandler block, everything works great.

Comment: is it working or not ?

Comment: no its not working. It showing empty content and after 4 seconds of wating the content gets filled. It should get filled immediatly

Comment: add that code. where that field filled .

Comment: I've updated the post. the code is filled by storyboard

Comment: which data filled after 4 seconds ?

Comment: the labels and buttons and everything. the only thing visible at start is the gray box with the border

Comment: is there you are used custom fonts ?

Comment: no, default system font

Comment: can you call your function to viewdidlayoutsubviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completion Handler Block is almost certainly running on a background thread. Try implementing your view load, setup and `addSubview` on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {  

       let myView = Bundle.loadView(fromNib: "PushNotificationPermissionView", withType: PushNotificationPermissionView.self)
        myView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        myView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        myView.center = self.view.center

        myView.layoutIfNeeded()

       self.addSubview(subView: myView, toView: self.view) 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I also did tried that and its not working. Still waiting about 4 seconds to the content is getting filled.

Comment: in the viewDidLoad function of the reresenting view controller

Comment: ok - instead of calling it directly, try putting this at the end of `viewDidLoad()` --- `self.perform(#selector(self.initPushNotificationDialog), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)`

Comment: Hi I found the solution. I have to create the whole view in the main thread. Now it loads the content directly. Can you please update your answer to that so I can accept it correctly? So the initialization of myView till the adding to the subview needs to be inside the main thread.